# Error sending email using Django with Celery

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm trying to send emails and below works perfectly fine if executed through the web server. However, when I try to send the task to Celery, I always get an Assertion Error returned telling me that "to" needs to be a list or tuple.

I don't want the emails to be sent via the web server as it will slow things down so if anyone can help me fix this, that would be greatly appreciated.

```
from celery import Celery
from django.core.mail import send_mail, EmailMessage

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def send_mail_link():
    subject = 'Thanks'
    message = 'body'
    recipients = ['someemail@gmail.com']
    email = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email='info@example.com', to=recipients)
    email.send()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure why, but I made some changes and it now works with no errors.

I removed the import for `send_mail` and changed the name of the method from `send_mail_link()` to `send_link()`. I also restarted the Celery worker and now everything works as it should.

New code is:

```
from celery import Celery
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage

app = Celery('tasks', backend='amqp', broker='amqp://')

@app.task
def send_link():
    subject = 'Thanks'
    message = 'body'
    recipients = ['someemail@gmail.com']
    email = EmailMessage(subject=subject, body=message, from_email='info@example.com', to=recipients)
    email.send()
```

Hopefully somebody in the future may find this helpful.

Comment: This does not work in production. Celery kicks back with an error. `ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type pickle (application/x-python-serialize)`. I need halp!!!!

Comment: Use `@app.task(serializer='json')` instead. Check out http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html#calling-serializers for more on serializers and why pickle is not supported by default.